# Partial form validation in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, safari

I am using the following javascript to validate the first part of my form in every browser except Safari:

```
var fields = $("#form input.initial-field"),
fieldsPass = false;

fields.each(function(x){
    if (!fields[x].checkValidity()) {
        $("#form").find(':submit').click();
    }
    for ( var x = 0; x < fields.length; x++ ) {
        if ( !fields[x].checkValidity() ) {
            fieldsPass = false;
        } else {
            fieldsPass = true;
        }
    }
});
if (fieldsPass == true) {
    Screens.showScreen();
    $(this.progressBar).addClass("two");
}
```

This function is being run on the click of a "Continue" button. Obviously, if I run this is Safari this continue button will submit my entire form.  Anyone have any ideas on what I can do for Safari?